# Объединить несколько директорий в одну виртуальную

Tags: windows

Есть приложение, которое можно расширить всякими дополнениями, закинув необходимые файлы в эту директорию, но со временем данная директория может стать не очень удобной в использование с кучей файлов и уже будет не понятно где оригинальные файлы, а где файлы дополнений.

Решил разделить все на директории:

1. Основная - в ней лежит само приложение.
2. Дополнительная - в ней лежат дополнительные файлы, которые должно подхватить приложение из основной директории.

И тут у меня возникла загвоздка, ибо я могу сделать к примеру жесткие ссылки на нужные мне файлы в основной директории, но в итоге я захламлю эту директорию также, если бы кидал файлы напрямую туда.

Вопрос: Может есть в Windows механизмы, которые позволяют сделать одну виртуальную директорию, которая будет содержать файлы других директорий?

Допустим:

- `dir1` - содержит файл `1.txt`
- `dir2` - содержит файл `program.exe`
- `virtualDir` - содержит в себе ссылки на `1.txt` и `program.exe`

И при запуске `virtualDir/program.exe` успешно бы открывалась программа, подгружая нужные данные.

Comment: Библиотеки такое делают, которые там "Документы, музыка" и т.п. можете свою создать так объединить, но хз получится ли созданную  библиотеку использовать как папку.

Comment: @teran Не думаю, что подойдет. Это не только для моих удобств делается, а для некоторого круга людей и даже если такое и работает - говорить им создать библиотеку для запуска приложения (а без дополнений проект не запустится) - согласитесь, не очень удобно, да и не каждый захочет там содержать что либо. Хотел это сделать как можно портативней, в крайнем случае сделать `.bat` файл, который создал бы необходимые ссылки сам.

Comment: но если сделать настоящую директорию virtualDir и накидать туда ссылок, то в чём разница? В чём должно быть отличие виртуальной директории от настоящей?

Comment: @PavelGridin Я хочу сделать так, что бы в директории с основным приложением не было вообще больше нечего, кроме самой программы, вот это моя основная цель. Я готов сделать "виртуальную директорию помойку", что бы программа через нее запускалась и там были бы все эти файлы в виде ссылок, но основная директория - должна быть девственно чиста.

Comment: ну так и сделать в этой "помойке" ещё ссылку на программу и запустить оттуда

Comment: @PavelGridin Увы, тут есть недостаток: У программы довольно много файлов, которые надо все переносить в эту "помойку" руками и если в самой программе произойдет добавление нового файла, то директории не будут синхронизироваться. Хотелось бы, что бы Windows сама понимала, что в этой директории находятся две другие.

Comment: библиотеку можно и программно создать. ну либо симлинки клепать в одну директорию из всех что надо, синхронизировать вручную.

Comment: @teran Я вчера долго размышлял как мне это грамотно сделать и вспомнил, что видел однажды программу, которая делала нечто подобное - это был Mod Organizer, который позволял отделить модификации и настройки от самой игры. Полазил в их документации и понял, что они используют [VFS](https://ru.bmstu.wiki/VFS_(Virtual_File_System)) - это некая абстрактная прослойка над основной файловой системой и вот походу для реализации того, чего я хочу, мне нужна будет именно она. Но пока увы, не знаю как ее грамотно реализовать...