# Виртуальная файловая система для объединения двух директорий

Tags: c#

Есть некое приложение (написанное не мной и доступа к нему нет), которое возможно расширить различными модификациями, делается это простым размещением .dll файлов рядом с основным .exe.

Со временем, у данного проекта накапливается очень много подобных расширений и главная директория превращается в помойку, где трудно найти оригинальные файлы и файлы расширений.

Сейчас решил побороть эту проблему и отделить модификации от основного приложения, поместив их в отдельную директорию, но вот незадача - проект переписать не могу, из другой директории он не регистрирует модификации. Думал решить эту проблему при помощи "символических ссылок" (и их аналогов), но попал в некий [тупик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1097471/220553), где мне пришлось бы уйму файлов прописывать вручную данными ссылками и если произойдет добавление/удаление чего либо, то опять же, создавать новую ссылку руками. Также для решения этой задачи при помощи ссылок, мне придется все перенаправлять в одну директорию, которая будет некой файловой помойкой и уже от туда запускать проект, согласитесь, не очень удобное решение...

Долго размышляя над этим всем я вспомнил, что довольно давно видел проект, который позволял отсоединить от игры профили, настройки, модификации и все остальное и делал это он все довольно элегантно, сохраняя все в одной директории игры. Звался тот проект `Mod Organizer`. Изучив особенности данной программы я понял, что они [используют](https://wiki.step-project.com/Guide:Mod_Organizer_Advanced) так называемую ["Виртуальную файловую систему" / VFS (Virtual File System)](https://ru.bmstu.wiki/VFS_(Virtual_File_System)), это как я понял некий абстрактный слой над основной файловой системой OS, который как-раз и позволит сделать то, чего я хочу.

Поискав хотя бы простую реализацию подобного, я наткнулся на библиотеки по типу [Zio](https://github.com/xoofx/zio), которые вроде это умеют делать, но как бы я их не крутил - результат нулевой, я не могу даже просто соединить две реальных директории в 1 виртуальную, уж про запуск программы я молчу..

**Вопрос:** Ребят, подтолкните на правильный путь, помогите реализовать VFS, которая соединила бы в себе две директории в 1 и запустила бы проект.

Пример директорий:

- До:

  `/App/Application.exe`
  `/App/SomeMod.dll`
  `/App/SomeMod2.dll`
- После:

  `/App/Application.exe`
  `/Modifications/SomeMod.dll`
  `/Modifications/SomeMod2.dll`

И при запуске `/App/Application.exe` программа находит все в `Modifications`, регистрирует их и успешно запускается.

Comment: сейчас от ищет dll в той же директории, что и exe файл или в рабочей директории?

Comment: @tym32167 Увы, в той же. Пытался менять рабочую директорию, не помогает. Единственное, что могу из рабочего сейчас сделать - это сделать символическую ссылку на длл из `/Modifications/SomeMod.dll` в `/App/SomeMod.dll`, но это равноценно тому, что я положу все в корень, ибо ссылками "засрется" основная директория.

Comment: я бы просто батник написал, который бы копировал прогу и модификации в Bin папку и оттуда запускал )

Comment: @tym32167 Модификаций порой может быть на несколько гигов и кидать их туда/обратно не очень целесообразно. Вот как бы с виртуальной файловой системой бы разобраться...

Comment: и вы эту систему будете на каждый клиент деплоить?

Comment: @tym32167 Если взять за пример `Mod Organizer`, то там простой клиент в пару мегабайт, через которого и идет запуск программы. Хотел бы реализовать также.

Comment: По ссылке же написано, что используется перехват функций WinAPI и дана ссылка с примером: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking Никакой "виртуальной файловой системы" как таковой в Windows не существует, это понятие взяли с потолка разработчики Mod Organizer. Есть NTFS Reparse Points, но они реализуются написанием своего драйвера - вряд ли это вам нужно. Библиотека Zio тут вообще не при чем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобных результатов можно достичь несколькими способами. Например вместо копирования файлов расширений туда-сюда можно создавать жесткие ссылки NTFS (hard links). Или использовать NTFS reparse points, простейшим случаем которых являются символические ссылки (symbolic links) и монтируемые папки, а более продвинутые сценарии использования требуют написания драйверов. Также существует альтернативный вариант с написанием расширения оболочки (Shell Namespace Extensions). Есть API для монтирования облачных файловых хранилищ (Сloud Sync Engines). Ну а в качестве более удобного варианта для локальной работы можно использовать API проецируемой файловой системы ([Projected File System (ProjFS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/projected-file-system)).

Этот вариант не требует написания драйверов, все делается в userspace буквально в несколько строк. Начинаете монтирование вызовом `PrjMarkDirectoryAsPlaceholder` указывая путь для монтируемой папки и придуманный GUID и запускаете обработчик вызовом `PrjStartVirtualizing` указывая путь для монтируемой папки и пачку функций обратного вызова в которых можно по-своему реализовать перечисление содержимого этой папки и доступ непосредственно к данным.

В качестве полноценного примере можно поглядеть [Virtual File System for Git](https://github.com/Microsoft/VFSForGit).

---

ЗЫ мне представляется, что для простого менеджера расширений будет более чем достаточно просто обрабатывать файлики с описанием расширений (то бишь со списком файликов, которые относятся к этому расширению) и переименовывать соответствующие `.dll` например в `.dll~` чтобы они не подгружались и обратно.

Answer (score 0):

---

А вот такое с dokan-ом ещё есть:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/winunionfs/